# Using Mock class with dependency injection in a JUnit test

Tags: spring, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

I have a basic Interface which another class is implementing.

```
package info;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

public interface Student 
{
    public String getStudentID();
}
```

`

```
package info;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Service
public class StudentImpl implements Student
{
    @Override
    public String getStudentID() 
    {
        return "Unimplemented";
    }
}
```

I then have a service to inject that class into

```
package info;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class InfoService {

    @Autowired
    Student student;

    public String runProg()
    {
            return student.getStudentID();
    }
}
```

What I want to know is, how do I set up a JUnit test so that a Mock class of the Student interface steps in with a stubbed method instead of the method in StudentImpl. The injection does work but I want to use amock class to simulate the results instead for the sake of testing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, autowiring in unit tests is a sign that's it's an integration test rather than unit test, so I prefer to do my own "wiring", as you describe. It might require you to do some refactoring of your code, but it shouldn't be a problem. In your case, I would add a constructor to `InfoService` that get's a `Student` implementation. If you wish, you can also make this constructor `@Autowired`, and remove the `@Autowired` from the `student` field. Spring would then still be able to autowire it, and it's also more testable.

```
@Service
public class InfoService {
    Student student;

    @Autowired
    public InfoService(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

}
```

Then it will be trivial to pass mocks between your services in your tests:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    Student mockStudent = mock(Student.class);
    InfoService service = new InfoService(mockStudent);
}
```

Comment: Is there anything special you have to place in the JUnit in order for this to work? The intention is to use `when(fakeStudent.getStudentId()).thenReturn("Some Value");`

Comment: No, in your test you would just create your mocks and then "wire" it up yourself. I added a simple example to the answer.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. I'm still getting the String from `StudentImpl`.

Comment: You might have to run the test without the standard JUnit runner. Not the one supplied by Spring. It will disable autowiring in your test.

Comment: It actually does work. I had been assigning an `ApplicationContext` and `BeanFactory` anytime I have Initialised the `InfoService`. Once I removed those from the test it started working.